# Auth0 can we avoid using the login popup?

Tags: auth0

I am new to Auth0. I was looking at the documentation and the how the users can login using the service. From what I read it seems that we need to have the popup for login. That could be customised to a certain extend but still we need it. Is that correct or I am missing something? I would like to have the freedom to be able to call api endpoint from auth0 and then handle the response without using the popup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to send user's credentials to your back-end and back-end to auth0.

For that you can use approach mentioned under [Resource Owner Password](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#resource-owner-password). This flow is defined in [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), under the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

Basically request should be something like this:

```
POST https://yoursubdomian.auth0.com/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "USERNAME",
  "password": "PASSWORD",
  "audience": "API_IDENTIFIER",
  "scope": "SCOPE",
  "client_id": "<your_client_id>",
  "client_secret": "<your_client_secret>"
}
```

For more details please refer [How to implement the Resource Owner Password Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant) article.

If you use above mentioned approach Please consider following statement as well.

> **Highly trusted** applications can use this flow to access APIs. In this
> flow the end-user is asked to fill in credentials (username/password),
> typically using an interactive form. This information is sent to the
> backend and from there to Auth0.

If you are trying to access Auth0 APIs from a client side app, then the best way to use [Implicit Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/implicit).